# Get object value with nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

I have a nested form (payments in an order) and I would like to test a value in my nested forms (fields_for) in edit view. But the problem is that I am not able to check each, I can just do this:

```
<% if @order.payments[0].monthly == false %>
```

Do you now how it is possible to check for each, like:

```
<% if @order.payments[current_payment].monthly == false %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand the question,  you are editing an order and have a `fields_for` for the payments and want to get the payment instance associated with the `fields_for`.  You can do that by calling `object` like below

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  = f.fields_for :payments do |ff|
    - payment_for_this_fields_for = ff.object # current payment object
```