# undefined method `persisted?' in link_to "Destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, persistence

The line `<%= link_to "Destroy", builder, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>` show the error

**No Method- undefined method persisted?**

Builder(Experience) is a nested attribute in User that allows destroy of experience

I had added the persisted? method in User and Experience controller but still not working.

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :experiences do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :title, class: 'form-control form-group' %>
    <%= link_to "Destroy", builder, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Experience Controller**

```
class ExperiencesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @experience = Experience.all
  end
def show
    @experience = Experience.find(params[:id])
end
def destroy
    @experience = Experience.find(params[:id])
    @experience.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed experience."
    redirect_to profile_path
end
def persisted?
  true
end
end
```

**Experience Model**

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates_presence_of :user
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :experiences
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
 end
```

**Routes**

```
experience GET    /experiences/:id(.:format)         experiences#show
                     PATCH  /experiences/:id(.:format)            experiences#update
                     PUT    /experiences/:id(.:format)         experiences#update
                     DELETE /experiences/:id(.:format)         experiences#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I was trying to delete a field_for and not the object of that field_for, I just add `builder.object` in link_to, like this

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", builder.object, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

This help me to found the solution [Get object value with nested_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208161/get-object-value-with-nested-form)